# Does Asp.net Webpages has something similar to Html.Partial in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I have an legacy application that was implemented in Asp.net Webpages. I am adding small section onto an old pages, but do not want to put all the code into one pages, which will be hard to read later.

is there anything similar to Html.Partial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have previously added MVC to an old Web Forms Application.  Created a div on a aspx page - and then when loading the page made an Ajax call to the MVC content and in the success handler of the ajax call render the html that was returned by the MVC controller (which was the razor page)

However if you want to stick to web forms a similar concept to Partial Pages would be Custom Controls which you can write and then re-use across multiple pages

Answer (score 2):

You can use UserControls (.ascx files), and use them across your webpages.

[Check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx)